# How can I optimize the following javascript code using vanilla js, using simple functions for a beginner?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, optimization

I am developing a website for a friend. The objective of the following code is to Give more information of specific items to the user using pop ups or modals.

**I managed to find a solution but I am sure I can optimize it or reduce the amount of code used. I would like to know how.**

Please ignore the content, is a website in spanish.

this is my HTML

```
    <div class="overlay hidden"></div>

<!-- This buttons open a specific modal -->
            <button type="button" class="products__cards__card" id="pa-card">
                <img src="assets/img/cards/piña.png" alt="pina-deshidratada">
                <div class="product-info">
                    <h3>Piña Golden</h3>
                    <p>Dulce y deliciosa</p>
                </div>
            </button>

            <button type="button" class="products__cards__card" id="arandano-card">
                <img class="os-img" src="assets/img/cards/arandano.png" alt="arandano-deshidratado">
                <div class="product-info">
                    <h3>Arándano</h3>
                    <p>El punto perfecto entre dulce y ácido</p>
                </div>
            </button>
```

```
<!-- This are the modals -->
        <div class="modal hidden" id="pa-modal">
            <h3>Piña Golden</h3>
            <p></p>
            <div class="modal__info">
                <span>100 gr.</span><span class="modal__info__price">S/16.00</span>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="modal-button button">Regresar</button>
        </div>


        <div class="modal hidden" id="arandano-modal">
            <h3>Arándano</h3>
            <p></p>
            <div class="modal__info">
                <span>100 gr.</span><span class="modal__info__price">S/18.00</span>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="modal-button button">Regresar</button>
        </div>
```

This is the Javascript i'm currently using to make the objective work. This is the code I would like to find a way to optimize:

```
//Card variables
const paButtonCard = document.querySelector("#pa-card");
const arandanoButtonCard = document.querySelector("#arandano-card");


//modal variables
const paModal = document.querySelector("#pa-modal");
const arandanoModal = document.querySelector("#arandano-modal");
const aguaymantoModal = document.querySelector("#aguaymanto-modal");


//Group variables
const closeModalButton = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

//Overlay
const overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");

// hide modals and overlay function
const closeModal = function () {
  overlay.classList.add("hidden");
  paModal.classList.add("hidden");
  arandanoModal.classList.add("hidden");
};

//Apply function to buttons in all modals
for (let i = 0; i < closeModalButton.length; i++) {
  closeModalButton[i].addEventListener("click", closeModal);
}

// Close overlay on click
overlay.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

// Open pina modal
paButtonCard.addEventListener("click", function () {
  paModal.classList.remove("hidden");
  overlay.classList.remove("hidden");
});

// Open arandano modal
arandanoButtonCard.addEventListener("click", function () {
  arandanoModal.classList.remove("hidden");
  overlay.classList.remove("hidden");
});
```

Comment: This should probably asked on [codereview.SE]. But, please read their [help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) pages before posting

Comment: anytime i see repeated code, i think "a function should be used instead". try to make the opener function generic. each one needs 2 pieces: the button name and modal name. add the modal name to the button, ex #arandano-card could have `data-modal="arandanoModal"`, so that you can use `document.querySelector("#"+this.dataset.modal).classList.remove("hidden");` ; a chunk without unique identifiers than need repeating. also, closeModal() should do something like `document.querySelector(".modal").forEach(e=>e.classList.add("hidden"));`; closing all of them each time so that you don't hard-code IDs

Comment: also, you can use the shorter `elm.hidden=true` instead of messing with hidden classes.